# Business Catalyst ICE not showing up

Tags: business-catalyst

I have enabled the ICE editable in Business Catalyst and edited a page to contain editable regions such as this:

```
<p ice:editable="multiline">Some text</p>
```

In the edit view the p tag doesn't contain ice:editable="multiline", and it is not editable. The changes have been published in the pages view so I don't know why it's not coming up. I tried editing the html directly in 'inspect element' but that didn't help either.

How come this p is not editable?

Answer (score 1):

Your code example is fine.

> I tried editing the html directly in 'inspect element' but that didn't help either.

The ICE parser has already processed the page by the time you modify the DOM from there, so changes will not be recognised.

> How come this p is not editable?

The ICE parser is very finicky at the moment, something as simple as nesting ICE regions will prevent them from appearing in the ICE editor. E.g., this works:

```
<div>
  <p ice:editable="multiline">
    The link <a href="#here2">here</a> is locked.
    This whole paragraph is <strong>editable</strong> (as "multiline" on the p tag).
  </p>
</div>
```

But this does not:

```
<div>
  <p ice:editable="multiline">
    The link <a href="#here2">here</a> is locked, but <a href="#this2" ice:editable="link">this</a> link is mutable.
    This whole paragraph <strong>should</strong> be editable (as "multiline" on the p tag), but the editable <code>
    &lt;a&gt;</code> interferes with it.
  </p>
</div>
```

Be aware that the `ice:` attributes are removed from rendered HTML in all views except the ICE Editor, accessible once you are logged in to the backend with the appropriate permissions.
The top of your admin pages should have an Edit button, like this:

[image: The Edit tab is at the top of the Admin pages.]

The editable tags should look like this, when hovered:

[image: How the working ICE Editor looks.]